# How do I handle keypresses in a form only if no child control already processed it?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Form which contains a number of controls, some of which are system controls and some of which are user controls. They may or may not be nested within containers. Some of these controls accept key input (think TextBox - in fact, some of them are just that).

I want to capture a particular keypress in this form. The keypress does not include modifier keys; for the purposes of this question, assume I want to detect when "X" is pressed and trigger some action when that happens. Normally, turning on KeyPreview or using ProcessCmdMsg would solve this problem.

However, I only want to do this if the control that would normally get the keypress event was not interested in it, or otherwise I end up triggering one of two unwanted behaviors: either "double input" where both the form action is triggered and an "X" is entered in the text box, or I eat the keypress and you can't type "X" in any of the form's textboxes. What I want is to only trigger the form action if the textbox (or whatever the focused control is) did not do anything with the keypress.

Naturally, this must be solved while still allowing system controls to be used throughout the form and not require something silly like overriding them with custom post-keypress behavior.

Comment: you can accomplish this by creating `Delegates` within the user control.. that's one way to handle it..

Comment: This is fundamentally not how keyboard processing works.  A keypress is only sent to the window with the focus, there is no bubbling.  Avoid asking an XY question and explain why you need this so that somebody can suggest an alternative.

Comment: When "X" is pressed in the form, a particular method needs to be called, but not if a control that did something useful with the keypress (like text entry) already did something with it. That really is what I need to do, and being mistrustful of the question is not helpful.

Comment: I think the best you could do is check `this.ActiveControl` and then process "X" at the Form level if it is not a TextBox, and not a xxx, and not a yyy, and not a zzz, etc.  `if (!(this.ActiveControl is TextBox) && ... )` Clunky indeed...